# Are there infinite primes of the form n!+1?

Tags: factorial

Are there infinite primes of the form n!+1 ? I searched the internet but couldn't find the answer.

Comment: Primes of the form $n!\pm1$ are called 'factorial primes'

Comment: It is an unsolved problem. See [here](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB4QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FFactorial_prime&ei=kJCJVIvwN4qgugStq4EI&usg=AFQjCNEGpD116eHvlsTGMq5dbHQO__sSzg&bvm=bv.81456516,d.c2E).